# Mathml is not rendered properly in inline html

Tags: html, mathml

It seems that even inline `<maths>` add extra spaces below and above the line. [As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcqCV.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwUvD.png). How can I avoid this behaviour ? Here is the code I used.

```
<p>
  The series
  <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display='inline'>
    <munderover>
    <mo>&sum;</mo>
    <mrow>
    <mi>n</mi>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mn>1</mn>
    </mrow>
    <mi>&infin;</mi>
    </munderover>
    <mfrac>
    <mn>1</mn>
    <mi>n</mi>
    </mfrac>
  </math>
  is divergent.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum a magna vel lorem auctor sagittis. Nullam viverra quam et quam sodales convallis. Donec felis nulla, scelerisque vel ante nec, ultricies viverra erat. Ut aliquet mollis dolor, sodales fringilla purus ultrices eu. Integer elit metus. 
</p>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a Js Fiddle to reproduce this issue? My best guess is, that it has to do with css (padding, margin, or line-height)

Comment: As you can see, the following jsfiddle is not able to reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/4td91d93/

Comment: If this is just about Firefox, then you might want to file a bug report with Mozilla (though it sounds like https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1208776, i.e., installing suitable fonts might help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so it seems that Linux on Ubuntu was not using the last of latin-modern, which caused the bug.
Following [this procedure](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lmodern/+bug/1502701/comments/3) has led to a correct rendering.